# While creating new column I get an error "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric."

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have been trying to make convert currency to euro, and take those all values into another column.

But I get the error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

The code is

```
SELECT 
    currency, gross_value,
    CASE
        WHEN currency = 'USD' THEN gross_value / 1.5
        WHEN currency = 'GBP' THEN gross_value * 0.92
        WHEN currency = 'AUD' THEN gross_value / 1.63
        WHEN currency = 'EUR' THEN gross_value
        WHEN currency IS NULL THEN gross_value
        ELSE gross_value
    END AS n_currency
FROM 
    [9-15-2020-Order];
```

I tried to add column first using alter, but it still shows the same error.

How do I solve this?

Note: all columns are `varchar` datatypes.

Thank you

Comment: "all columns are varchar datatypes." that is your problem. Why isn't `gross_value` a decimal?

Comment: Why are you storing values such as `gross_value` as a string?  You clearly have bad values in that column.  Fix the data!

Comment: This causes the error `gross_value/1.5`.

Comment: Assuming you cannot fix the datatype issue at this point (I've been there) what do you want to happen with values that aren't numerical?

Comment: How gross_value/1.5 giving error?

Comment: And you also have `Strict SQL Mode` enabled, correct?

Comment: I'm gonna fix the data first and check whether I still get an error. Thanks

Comment: Yes! It is enabled.

Comment: That is why this happens https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict you can fix this by changing to `CAST(gross_value AS UNSIGNED)`.

Comment: But as commented in the beginning run a thorough check in your tables and assign the proper datatype to each column.